# SQLAlchemy session.query(object) returns automap object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm going through the sqlalchemy learning curve and I'm going round in circles, a bit. My SQL is rather rusty (maybe primitive) and I want to use the ORM capabilities in a new project I'm about to start, so I'm doing some initial hacking as I build up some confidence in it.

I'm running on a macOS 10.15.4 and this is my environment, which is all current along with all the python packages, if it's relevant.

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 28 2020, 12:50:30)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin

pyodbc            4.0.30
SQLAlchemy        1.3.15
```

I'm trying to display, what I think, is a simple `SELECT * FROM table` query, and just print out the row (as in the data in the row). But, when I run the following code, I just get a list of objects and not the data. All the references I've seen suggest this should work and I can access specific columns, like the examples. I can use even `.___dict___` to display as a Python dictionary (not shown as it has private data in it), and I get the key:value pairs, but also the "'_sa_instance_state': " as well. Is there a method or another way to access the data without having to know / specify the column name as an attribute, e.g. 'Answer.Answer_Id'?

But, I'm going round in circles with the reference documentation and my GoogleFu is letting me down. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://%s' % con_string)
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

Answer = Base.classes.Answer

session = Session(bind=engine)
query = session.query(Answer).limit(10).all()
for row in query:
    print(row)
```

This is the result that I get:

```
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0b80>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0c10>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0e80>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0ee0>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0f40>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0fa0>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb0fd0>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb5070>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb5100>
<sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Answer object at 0x10ddb5190>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I swap the `print(row)` for `print(row.AnswerId)`, I get data:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: An ORM usually returns mapped objects as query results, as is happening here. In other words it is working as expected. Those objects contain the data in object form.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thank you. I can see they are objects. But, what I'm trying to do is get to the data in the object without having to know all the column names, I guess that would have been helpful (now added). Is the only way to use  `__dict__` ?

Comment: If you want raw data, as opposed to objects, you're better off using the reflection features in sqlalchemy core https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html